# Characteristic function and third moment

Tags: random-variables, irrational-numbers, characteristic-functions

Examining a problem I find that: 
$E[(Y_n)^3] = \sum_{i=1}^nE[(X_i)^3]$. Where $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

Now, I'm not able to understanding the following step:
$$\phi^{'''}_{Y_n}(0) = - i\sum_{i=1}^nE[(X_i)^3]$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

I think that they applied the following formula: $E[(Y_n)^3] = (-i)^3\phi^{(3)}_{Y_n}$.  And then they move the "i" in the other side. But I'm not able to understand how. Because in my computation I have to multiply in both side for "i" at the power of something, therefore I never have $i^1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They did exactly as you said but simplified it: $\frac{1}{(-i)^3} = -i$.

Reason:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(-i)^3} &= \frac{1}{(-1)^3i^2 i}\\
&=\frac{1}{(-1)(-1)i}\\
&= \frac{1}{i}\\
&= -i.
\end{align*}
The reason that $\frac{1}{i}=-i$ is because $i\cdot (-i) = -i^2 = 1$.

Comment: how do you obtain such a simplification? I hope that is because my brain is exploding that I'm not able to see it

Comment: @Alberto__ See my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of the characteristic function
$$
\phi_X(t)=\mathbb Ee^{itX}.
$$
Thus, if we take derivatives with respect to $t$ inside the expectation we have
$$
\phi_X^{(n)}(t)=\mathbb E(iX)^ne^{itX}. 
$$
Now set $t=0$ so that
$$
\phi_X^{(n)}(0)=\mathbb E(iX)^n.
$$
I think your question is answered by the case $n=3$.